Location of Vena contracta
Is it possible to calculate the location of vena contracta downstream of an orifice? I am interested to see if for a fixed geometry, the location of vena contracta depends on the flowrate (velocity)?
(Suppose a steady, incompressible, Newtonian flow)

General remarks about fluid dynamics
Besides the unclear definition of "vena contracta", I'd like to stress here some aspects about fluid dynamics:

fluid dynamics is governed by non linear equations, so the mathematical problem is usually hard to solve and thus accurate predictions hard to be made with simple calculations;
fluid dynamics is "case dependent", meaning that it's usually either hard or WRONG to generalize (or a combination of them)  results on different flows, and with some more details:

the flow is likely to depend on the actual geometry of the bodies involved; the mathematical problem is a set of partial differential equations with proper initial and boundary conditions (proper = representative of your system and consistent);
the flow is likely to be strongly influenced by the flow regime, usually summarized with the value of a set of non-dimensional numbers, like Reynold's number, Mach's number, Froude's number,...


some flows may be strongly influenced by very-small amplitude disturbances (usually called noise amplifiers, if you want a key word to google)

Approach
Thus, it's likely you need to rely on either:

numerical methods and simulations performed by you or someone else who has published the results; remember that you need to reproduce noise and disturbances representative of the ones acting on the real system, if you want to get reliable results
semi-empirical laws

about the system you are interested in, with the very same geometry and non-dimensional parameters.
